# Jenkins Multi-Configuration Build - How do I specify the value of a multi-configuration axis in Email-Ext (Editable Email Notification)?

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've searched and have not found what content token that I would use to note the value of an axis that is used on a multi-configuration build for the email?

This shows up in the normal email but is a blocker for us getting to the better email notifications?

I will accept that this is in an ENV variable somewhere, but have been unable to locate it yet.

## For reference

We'd typically add an axis of a label, slaves or user-defined (image below):
[image: Adding axis]

Then we would add values:
[image: User defined axis]

Those values show up in the normal email notification (note the `>>` to signify all axes of the multi-configuration build that passed or failed:
[image]

I can not seem to get to them in email. I've tried looking for environment specific values and I've tried `${ruby}` as a content token, but have been unable to find any information on this thus far.

Comment: Filed https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=418386 and waiting on the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to not selecting `Trigger for each configuration` in the `Trigger for matrix jobs`. When defining an axis like ruby, one would get ahold of it by `${ruby}` or possibly `${ENV,"ruby"}`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `${axis}`?

Also, looks like env vars for axis config are exposed like this:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/701

Comment: Ha! I saw that somewhere but never thought to try the literal `${axis}`, instead trying `${ruby}` when the axis was labeled `ruby`. We'll see if that works.